# what to do with cartitems in db when a shoppingcart is cleared

Tags: java, jpa, mapping, shopping-cart

I have a `ShoppingCart` which has a set of `CartItem` objects .When I save the shoppingcart,all the cartitems are also saved.When the buyer confirms a buy,I need to clear the shoppingcart.If I save the cart to the db now,what should happen to the cartitems already saved in the db and associated with the cart?Should I remove them from db?

The jpa mappings of Entities are

```
@Entity
class ShoppingCart{
...
   @OneToOne
   public Buyer buyer;

   @OneToMany(mappedBy="cart", cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    public Set<CartItem> cartItems;
 ...
}

@Entity
public class CartItem{
   @ManyToOne
   public ShoppingCart cart;

@OneToOne
   public Product pdt;
   public int quantity;
...

} 
}
```

the shoppingcart table in db

```
id  | buyer_id 
-----+-------------
 100 |   50
```

cartitem table can be

```
 id  | quantity | product_id | cart_id 
-----+----------+------------+---------
 12  |        2 |     234    |  100
--------------------------------------
 13  |       4  |     231    |  100
```

So after I clear the shoppingcart and save it to db,if these items are still in db,it would mean that cartitem 12 still refers to cart 100.But ,cart with id=100 has no cartitems since I have cleared them.
So,is clearing a cart and saving it to db equivalent to deleting the cart?
How do I map this behaviour?Or is there a flaw in my thinking?

Comment: Check if your JPA provider supports something like Hibernate "delete-orphan", as JPA doesn't provide something like this.

Comment: Why do you need to save the shopping cart? Can it be reused in different sessions?

Comment: I am assuming that state of cart in the app at any moment should be same as its state in db

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't posted code on how you are clearing the shopping cart, so my answer will make a fair number of assumptions.

Going by the contents of the tables, I'll assume that you've invoked `cartItems.clear()` in your `ShoppingCart` class. The problem with this invocation is that your relationship is bidirectional and therefore a `CartItem` instance will continue to have a reference back to the `ShoppingCart` instance, although the opposite isn't true. Depending on what JPA provider you are using, clearing the `Set` and updating the persistence context contents with the database will either not clear the `cartitem` table or will throw an exception stating that the `cart_id` cannot be null (if your foreign keys are not nullable).

The fix in most JPA providers (especially in Hibernate) is to clear the reference to the `ShoppingCart` in the `CartItem` instance in addition to the `cartItems` Set in `ShoppingCart`. Note that, if you choose to deleted orphaned entries using the [`orphanRemoval`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/OneToMany.html#orphanRemoval%28%29) attribute of the `@OneToMany` annotation (supported since JPA 2.0), then all orphaned `CartItems` (that are not referenced by a `ShoppingCart`) will also be deleted in the database, on clearing the bidirectional relationship. Without the `orphanRemoval` attribute set to true, your JPA provider will make no attempt to delete `CartItem`s that are no longer referenced by a `ShoppingCart`; the transaction will eventually be successful depending on whether your foreign key in the cartitem table is nullable or not.

If you intend to retain the `CartItem` records in the database, but merely nullify the reference to the `ShoppingCart`, then you ought to designate the reference as nullable (using the `@Column` annotation, and also have the table defined to have a nullable foreign key).

Answer (score 1):

You can either use orphanRemoval (JPA 2), or call em.remove() for each item.

See,
http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Relationships#Orphan_Removal_.28JPA_2.0.29

Otherwise, the items will still be there.

If you want the items to remain in the database, then just set their cart to null to remove them from the cart.